# How does one create a style sheet for Sibelius?

Tags: sibelius

I am new here, and pretty new to Sibelius.  I am interested in creating my own individual style sheet for Sibelius, specifically to have the Composer and Lyricist BOTH right justified, header/title/creators in Arial, and copyright to be in Arial. Essentially to look similar to the most common sheet music layout/format.  Is there any way to do this?

Basically, what I am looking for is in the photo below (I did it in Word, because I couldn't figure out how to in Sib  [image: The format I would like to use]

Thank y'all!

Answer (score 1):

You do this by editing the appropriate Text Styles - Title Text, Copyright Text etc. - and , when you have a score looking how you like it, Export a Manuscript Paper (or just a House Style) for use in future scores.

You might find a lot of what you want is included in one of the supplied House Styles that use Arial.   [image]